# Sass and appending parent class

Tags: css, sass

Is there a way to do something in SASS below where the -center gets appended to the part to add a center? I'd like both to have the 110px but the -center to have the center alignment.

```
 .table-col-sm {
        width: 110px;
    }

    .table-col-sm-center {
        width: 110px;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

I went ahead and did this.

```
$column-widths: ( "sm" : ("width": 110px), "md": ( "width": 160px));

 @each $col, $values in $column-widths {
        .table-col-#{$col} {
             width: map-get($values, "width");
        }
        .table-col-#{$col}-center {
             width: map-get($values, "width");
             text-align: center;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately You have to write the `width` attribute twice, but yes there is a way. Btw, If you'd like to see more what you can do with the parent selector in SASS look it up [here](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector)

```
.table-col-sm
  width: 110px

  &-center
    width: 110px
    text-align: center
```

Comment: Ill have to make a variable then for the 11px, but this will work

Answer (score 0):

Unsure what you mean by append, but here are a couple of options:

```
   <div>
       <p class="table-col-sm text-center w--110"></p>
   </div>

  <style>
    .table-col-sm {
    &.center {
         text-align: center;
     }
    &.w--110 {
         width: 110px;
     }
    }
  </style>
```

option 2

```
    <div class="table-col-sm">
        <p class="text-center w--110"></p>
    </div>

    <style>
        .table-col-sm {
        & p  {
              text-align: center;
          }
        & .w-110 {
             width: 110px;
         }
        }
    </style>
```